# I want to list the databases when user name and password are entered in server name using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have server name username and password in my connection string. I want to list the databases that are connected to that server when it comes to values. How can I do?

Comment: Hello murat, welcome to StackOverflow. I find it hard to understand your question. What do you mean by *"[...] when it comes to values"*? *[Not my downvote]*

Answer (score 0):

if you have a valid connection string and want to get all connected databases this is how you would have to do it:

```
        DataTable databaseNames = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases; ";
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        databaseNames.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

databaseNames table will contain 1 column named "name" and all the names as rows.